# How can I create a single repo with code for multiple lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to create an API using API Gateway, with multiple Lambda functions to handle the requests (rather than one single monolithic lambda function).

Is there a best practice for defining & building multiple lambda function handlers in the same project repository?

Comment: take a look at aws SAM @ https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/ or Serverless framework @ https://www.serverless.com  Also this blog
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/

Comment: You can check aws provided solutions for patterns, e.g. [video-on-demand-on-aws](https://github.com/awslabs/video-on-demand-on-aws) project.